# Trouble submitting form using .get

Tags: jquery, forms, xmlhttprequest

I've searched the forums for a while and although I have found posts where there is useful information, I have not been able to get any of it to work.  Here is a summary of my desired behavior.

I have a HTML page with jquery that is used to read in my user name/password from a file in order to log into a server.  My page has a form with method="post" and I've been told that in order to log into this server prior to submitting the form, I could use this in my  section.

```
<script>
   var xmlhttp;
   if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
      xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else {
      xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    var url = "http://sasserver.com:8080/SASStoredProcess/do?_username=USERl&_password=PWD";
    xmlhttp.open("GET", url, false);
    xmlhttp.send();
    if (xmlhttp.status != 200) {
      console.log("Unable to retrieve: " + url);
      alert("Open error: " + url);
    }
</script>
```

This works, but it does not read in my username and password.  I currently have jquery set up to do that.

```
get('http://server.com/pw.dat',function(result){
        var perLine=result.split(':');
        $('input[id=usernm]').val(perLine[0]);
        $('input[id=pass]').val(perLine[1]);
            var u = $("#usernm").val(); 
            var p = $("#pass").val(); 
        });
```

My issue is how to complete replace the XMLHttpRequest logic with jquery logic so I can submit this form on $(document).ready.

I am able to create a variable containing the correct url, but the .get method is not working.  I want to do this synchronously (at least that's how the XMLHttpRequest worked).

I saw that I could use $.ajaxSetup({async:false}); to allow this prior to using .get, but its not working.

Please assist me in determining if my code is just out of order or if there is a larger issue at hand.  I am trying to do this using (document).ready because the HTML page has a form to submit as well (method=post).

My current code block:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajaxSetup({async:false});
    $.get('http://server.com/pw.dat',function(result){
        var perLine=result.split(':');
        $('input[id=usernm]').val(perLine[0]);
        $('input[id=pass]').val(perLine[1]);
//  var u = $("#usernm").val(); 
//  var p = $("#pass").val(); 

        });

    var u = $("#usernm").val(); 
    var p = $("#pass").val(); 
    var url="http://sasserver.com:8080/SASStoredProcess/do?_username=" + u + "&_password=" + p;
    alert(url); //check to make sure we have the url
    $.get(url);
    $.ajaxSetup({async:true});
});


</script>
```

Thanks.

Comment: First of all: `async:false` is the root of all evil. Don't use it. Second of all: what do you mean it doesn't work? What errors do you get in console?

Comment: I know its the less desirable way to go, but I have a simple need to submit the form to login into the server so I tried it.  I'll take whatever works.   Regarding console, I am not using that, I basically make the HTML page and test it in IE.  I'm not a web developer so my tools are limited.

Comment: @Ben the `console` is part of the web inspector, which is readily available in almost all browsers today. If you don't have a web inspector, download one. usually pressing `F12` will invoke the web inspector, then you get a UI interface, where you can select the `Console` tab, which will display any errors/warnings you may be receiving.

Comment: That's right, just press F12 in IE and it opens the web debugger. The one in Chrome is better in many ways; I recommend that one. Whatever you do, you really can't be using `async:false`. You need to find a proper asynchronous solution. It isn't hard to do. You just have to use the callback functions and take action there, instead of relying on data being ready when `$.get()` returns.

Comment: F12 in IE got me into the developer tools, although I don't know where to go from here.  I don't see any errors in console.  If I try this in async mode (the xmlHttprequest) then I get an error in IE "unspecified error" right before  if (xmlhttp.status != 200).

Comment: I should also note that I tried .get without turning async off and on, it also did not work (meaning I was still prompted to log in).

Comment: UPDATE - I decided I would try the simplest approach.  I just inserted the xmlhttprequest code into my jquery block and it works.  I'm curious what the right jquery solution is, but at least for now I have a workable solution.